# How to change the border style of a child window?

Tags: winapi

I created a window with three child windows in it and set the child windows style to `WS_THICKFRAME`, so that the user can change their size. But the new frame coming with it, doesn't suit to it's purpose. So is there an easy way to change the frame's style to only a line? (Such at there is at the `WS_BORDER` style)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think WS_THICKFRAME is compatible with child windows, though I can't find anything in the documentation that says that specifically.  WS_THICKFRAME is intended for top-level windows and some pop-up windows.

WS_BORDER on a child window will (for most types of child windows) give you a single line border, but this is just a visual embellishment.  It won't allow the user to resize the child.

To make resizable children, you'll have to add your own logic to handle the click-and-drag operations.  There are various ways to do this, but all the details are probably beyond the scope of a SO answer.